# Pre-load/render ajax requests in Nuxt for AMP

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, amp-html, server-side-rendering

The last few days I read a lot about VueJS and AMP. My goal is to create a website/blog with VueJS and to obtain the option to deploy it to Google News etc. (AMP related stuff).
I discovered NuxtJS, which should enable me to create SSR sites using VueJS. And yes - it does, but the result is still using some heavy JS for my REST requests to get some stuff (e.g. text, names).

I could indeed use something like https://github.com/nuxt-community/amp-module , but this would require me to change a lot of source code and to make my source code incompatible with normal browsers...

I also had the idea to execute all the javascript using NodeJS for some routes (only "articles" etc. would be affected), but then I wouldn't be able to use stuff like "v-for" - except I change the source code itself, but this would be a huge project for me in the end of the day.

Another "brilliant" idea I had was to start a chromium instance on the server, let chromium render everything and to (however) get the final DOM. But currently I'm not a C++ dev so this would also be a huge deal.

Has anyone experience how to use VueJS with AMP (without changing the source code a lot) or points/articles to start?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I decided to use NuxtJS for static rendering (SSR).

Here are the steps I take for an AMP valid page:

- Make everything visible without JS (except your Ajax logic)
- Put your Ajax logic in #asyncData -> https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data (asyncData will be fetched to *generation* time)
- npm run generate -> generate static html files
- Use a custom (Java) server(or write a plugin) to request the page (including JS)
- Transform everything
- Add "amp" to the header
- Add the amp style & script boilerplate (see below)
- Change `<img` to `<amp-img`
- Remove every JS tag via RegEx
- Change `<style` to `<style amp-custom`
- Add a *canonical* link to your head (see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/?format=websites)
- get the images and add the height, width & layout attributes to the tags
- ( https://validator.ampproject.org/ )
- Serve the page to the user (and cache it)

(Untested) page example:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div v-if="content != null">{{ content }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Axios from "axios";

    export default {

        asyncData() {
            return Axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/content`).then(res => {
                return { content: res.data }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```